# how to check if XML is loaded in VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vba

I have this code in VB6 for search a postcode  in Brazil:

```
MousePointer = 11
Dim xlink As String
Set myXML = New DOMDocument
myXML.resolveExternals = True
myXML.validateOnParse = True
myXML.async = False
xlink = "http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=" & cep & "&formato=xml"
myXML.Load (xlink)
```

The URL fails many times i want to add a second link

```
xlink2 = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/" & cep & " /xml"
```

I want to know if myxml have loaded 15  sec , if delay more than 15 load another link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Use the onReadyStateChange Property (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: If you are using VBA do not tag your question VB6.